# Spark groupByKey unable to interpret lambda functions for known fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, group-by, apache-spark-dataset

I have two datasets, ds1 and ds2 which have the following respective schema:

**addressDS:**

```
> addressDS.printSchema()
root
 |-- endId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parentId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- countries: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
```

**edgeDS:**

```
edgeDS.printSchema()
root
 |-- endId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- startId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- edgeType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- link: string (nullable = true)
```

I performed an inner join on these two datasets as such:

```
> val joinedDS = addressDS.join(edgeDS, "endId")
> joinedDS.printSchema()
root
 |-- endId: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- parentId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- countries: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- startId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- edgeType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- link: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, the Spark interpreter knows the schema to be the combination of both. Next I would like to perform a `groupByKey` on the resultant Dataset on the field `startId`. However despite the fact that this schema is known to the Spark interpreter, it is unable to do so, yielding the following error:

```
> val groupedDS = joinedDS.groupByKey{ x => x .startId }
<console>:38: error: value startId is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
       val groupedDS = joinedDS.groupByKey{ x => x.startId }
```

I did a lot of research on this topic. The syntax for the `groupByKey` function in Scala is as such:

`groupByKey[K](func: (T) ⇒ K)(implicit arg0: Encoder[K]): KeyValueGroupedDataset[K, T]`

In this example, my curly brackets are syntactic sugar, representing the lambda function:

```
(x: Row) => x.getAs[String]("startId")
```

The compiler should be able to infer this because based on the schema it knows that the `startId` type is a `String`. But apparently not and I have to explicitly type out:

```
> val groupedDS = joinedDS.groupByKey{ x => x.getAs[String]("startId") }
```

Despite the fact that the schema is known, why can't Spark infer this type? Why do I have to manually set the type using a `.getAs`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the fact that a [`Row` object](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala) does not have a method called `startId`, which is what you're actually asking the compiler to do when writing `joinedDS.groupByKey{ x => x .startId }`.

How do we know that `x` is a `Row` object in that line of code? Well, your `joinedDS` is the output of [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5B_%5D,usingColumn:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) `join` method, which has the following signature:

```
def join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumn: String): DataFrame
```

You have a `DataFrame` as an output, and a `DataFrame` == `Dataset[Row]`.

So in your `groupByKey` function, your `(func: (T) ⇒ K)` from the signature you posted is your function `x => x.startId`. But in this case we know that `T == Row` so you're asking the `Row` object to have a `startId` method, which it does not have.

### How can we solve this?

If you want to use the notation you wanted, you'll need to create a `Dataset[someClass]` to be able to use `.startId`. You can do this by typing your dataset.

Let's first create some fake data:

```scala
val addressDS = Seq(("myEndId", "myParentId", "myAddress", "myCountry", "sourceId"))
  .toDF("endId", "parentId", "address", "countries", "sourceId")

val edgeDS = Seq(("myEndId", "myStartId", "myEdgeType", "myLink"))
  .toDF("endId", "startId", "edgeType", "link")
```

Now that we have your data, and we know what the output type is going to be, we can use that to turn your `Dataset[Row]` into a `Dataset[MyType]` and do your `groupByKey`:

```scala
case class MyType(
  endId: String,
  parentId: String,
  address: String,
  countries: String,
  sourceId: String,
  startId: String,
  edgeType: String,
  link: String
)

val joinedDS = addressDS.join(edgeDS, "endId").as[MyType]

val groupedDS = joinedDS.groupByKey{ x => x .startId }
groupedDS: org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[String,MyType] = KeyValueGroupedDataset: [key: [value: string], value: [endId: string, parentId: string ... 6 more field(s)]]
```